# Hangfire tables are not created

Tags: c#, hangfire

This is my code in C# NET 6

```
builder.Services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(connectionstring));
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();

... 

app.UseHangfireDashboard();
```

The code runs without error, but the hangfire tables are not created

Comment: I think you need to call this also : ``app.UseHangfireServer()``

Comment: Good, is it required to make an answer maybe other guys need it in future?